# Is there a way to auto import REFERENCE DATA / COLOR instead of manually adding the new colors?

Tags: colors, akeneo

We use RICS that auto import our product information into Akeneo. Every time there is a new COLOR, I get an error for example: **Property "color" expects a valid reference data code. The code "BALTIK/LAKE" of the reference data "color" does not exist** under CONNECT/CONNECTION SETTINGS/ERROR MONITORING, so I then manually add each color under REFERENCE DATA/(_T) SIMPLE ASSETS. Is there a way Akeneo can be set up to auto add these new colors in the REFERENCE DATA as there are hundreds of new colors needing to be added frequently?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which type of attribute do you have.

If you have attribute type `Reference entity simple link` there is no job to import the records. You can do this by writing a simple script using REST API.

If you have attribute type `Simple select` there is dedicated import job, and you can prepare CSV or XLSX with all possible values. Then you can import it to PIM. You can do this via API too.

Additionally, there is no possibility to new `option`/`record` on the go while importing the product. There are a couple of plugins in marketplace which does that, but it's really bad for catalog hygiene and can cause a lot of problems for system operators.